# How to use an application as gateway in c# application?

Tags: c#, c++, vb.net, exe

I have a client application which has complete functions to communicate and work with servers. The Client application written in c++ and vb and doesn't have user friendly GUI.

So, I designed a GUI for it and try to communicate by servers.
Server application does not provide any web service and I decide to use current application as gateway. But How?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please provide more detail. *What* is it you are having problems with?

Comment: This application is a warehouse application which has transaction with servers. I can not direct communicate to servers. my question is: how I can send request to client application and get result from it? Thanks for your attention

Comment: notice i've not any source of client application

Comment: How would we know how you can communicate with your client application? We know even less than you do about it. Does it take command line arguments? Is it open to network communication of some sort? What interface does it have?

Comment: This is my question too. How I can communicate with client application and get result from it? only I see a record script section and a run script button in application which can useful for this question. client application use TCP for communicate with server. I capture transmitted data packets in wireshark, but I don't know how to analysis and use it and I decide to use different solution.

Comment: Why don't you ask the application's vendor to provide documentation?

Comment: I asked it, they purchase this application from Liquidated company and  but they don't decide to improve any features. Current features working properly but don't have appropriate GUI.